# Curl error when try to download file using Dropbox API

Tags: php, curl, dropbox-api, dropbox-php

This is my first attempt using Dropbox API and I'm just following the "Hello World" from PHP SDK. Upload methods is working fine, but download:

```
$app = new DropboxApp("...", "...", "...");
$dropbox = new Dropbox($app);
$file = $dropbox->download("/image.png", '/image.png');
```

Return this warning:

> Warning: curl_exec(): Could not call the CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION in
>   /srv/www/website/public_html/dropbox/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlHandler.php
>   on line 40
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Unable to open /image.png
>   using mode w+: fopen(/image.png): failed to open stream: Permission
>   denied in
>   /srv/www/website/public_html/dropbox/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/functions.php:299
>   Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: GuzzleHttp\Psr7{closure}(2,
>   'fopen(/unifeal-...', '/srv/www/website/...', 307, Array) #1
>   /srv/www/website/public_html/dropbox/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/functions.php(307):
>   fopen('/image.p...', 'w+') #2
>   /srv/www/website/public_html/dropbox/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/LazyOpenStream.php(37):
>   GuzzleHttp\Psr7\try_fopen('/image.p...', 'w+') #3
>   /srv/www/website/public_html/dropbox/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/StreamDecoratorTrait.php(31): GuzzleHttp\Psr7\LazyOpenStream->createStream() #4
>   /srv/www/website/public_html/dropbox/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/StreamDecoratorTrait.php(136):
>   GuzzleHttp\Psr7\LazyOpenStream->__get('stream') #5
>   /srv/www/website/public_html/dropbox/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php(380):
>   GuzzleHttp\Psr7\LazyOpenStream-> in
>   /srv/www/website/public_html/dropbox/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/functions.php
>   on line 299

I'm testing using Vagrant.

**UPDATE**

I can confirm that is not a permission issue because download works using this script:

```
$file = $dropbox->download("/image.png");
$contents = $file->getContents();
file_put_contents(__DIR__ . "/image.png", $contents);
$metadata = $file->getMetadata();
```

But not using the recommended way.

Comment: check the permissions on `image.png`

Comment: @gogaz the file permissions inside Dropbox environment?

Comment: i had this problem.  the file i was trying to upload didn't exist